# Node.js session remember me access user email when logged out?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

Similar to the google login https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin when you check "stay signed in" log in then log out, you have the email field filled out as well as your image.

I think this is a cool UI feature to have, so I implemented https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me but the cookie is only available when logged in, logging out destroys the cookie.

So messing around I did this

```
// when the user logs in 
User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }, function (err, user) {

    user.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.log('error');
        else 
            res.render('app', { user: req.user }); 
            res.cookie('testCookie', req.user.local.email, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
    });

});
```

I will need validation and only set the cookie if `req.body.remember_me` is true, but for now this sets a cookie like this

[image]

Then when I render the login page I do this

```
res.render('login', { user: req.cookies.testCookie });
```

Obviously I don't think this is good, but I am confused what is the purpose of https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me if I can't access data for the logged out user?

Looking at googles cookies they don't expose the email like I did it looks like this

[image]

Looking at it there is an `ID=b1051bd`.

So IDK any help would be great, I am trying to remember the user that checked the remember me box when logged out.

Comment: use localStorage instead of cookies.

Comment: Does this look good? https://www.npmjs.org/package/store

Comment: Seems good, thanks for the tip. I know google isn't always perfect, but why wouldn't they use localStorage?

Comment: logistics: servers can see cookie, they cannot see localStrorage. but for a ui feature, the server need not know.

Comment: Ah okay, so for little ol' me localStorage should suffice! lol thanks

Comment: they probably just use cookies for everything to get ie7/dino support, or maybe it's to sync settings across devices, as localStorage would affect just the one device, or maybe they are just nosy.